# jQuery init function with condition

Tags: jquery, initialization, init

I am new to scripting side and again need your help to write better code. I am using init function which is a collection of all functions, but now there seems to be few functions that I want to be executed if certain condition is true.

**SAMPLE SCRIPT**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

var app = {
init: function(){

  // Variable to check condition
  var abc = 0;

  // Default functions
  this.Function1();
  this.Function2();
  this.Function3(); // abc variable will change to 1 if condition is true

  // Conditional functions
  if ( abc === 1 ) {
     this.ConditionFunction1();
     this.ConditionFunction2();
  },

  Function1: function(){ // some Code },
  Function2: function(){ // some Code },
  Function3: function(){
                if(true) { abc == 1; } 
  },
  ConditionFunction1: function(){ // some Code },
  ConditionFunction2: function(){ // some Code }

}
app.init();
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here - `abc` is hard-coded to `0`, so your condition will never hit. If you want to perform some logic when the `abc` value changes, I'd suggest you use an event based patter instead.

Comment: Those Function: are inside Init(), you should place them outside.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan friend can u explain a bit please about the event based patter? 'abc' is some dummy variable that i was trying to apply condition.

Comment: @Zorkind which functions to put outside? the condition functions will cacheDOM some elements if called.

Comment: after the conditional you place some functions with comma, i figure those should be out of Init()? the way it is, everything is inside Init() except for ConditionalFunctions that is

Comment: @Zorkind they seems to work fine but if placing them outside will make code more efficient then i will just do it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rewriting and by orientate on your code you could write it like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var app = {
        init: function () {

            // Variable to check condition
            var abc = 0;
            var Function1 = function () { // some Code
                console.log("Function1")
            }

            Function2 = function () { // some Code
                console.log("Function2")

            }

            Function3 = function () {
                if (true) {
                    console.log("Function3")
                    abc == 1;
                }
            }

            ConditionFunction1 = function () { // some Code
                console.log("ConditionFunction1")
            }

            ConditionFunction2 = function () { // some Code
                console.log("ConditionFunction2")
            }
            // Default functions
            Function1();
            Function2();
            Function3(); // abc variable will change to 1 if condition is true

            // Conditional functions
            if (abc === 1) {
                ConditionFunction1();
                ConditionFunction2();
            }
        }
    }
    app.init();
});
```

Comment: never thought it would be that easy :)

Thanks friend